# Find all non-overlapping regions from a graph of connected bezier paths

Tags: algorithm, vector, graph, region, bezier

i have this:
A set of edges, where an edge contains:

- a vector of conected bezier curves (the geometry)
- a set of pointers to the neihboor edges on each end
- pointers to two regions adjacent to the edge ( null at begining)

  Class Edge{
      vector neighbors[2];
      Region* regions[2];
      BezierPath geometry; 
  }

there is no intersecting edges in the plane
i want to find all the non-overlapping regions on the plane surrounded by the edges

example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s31QG.png

do you know an algorithm for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that by "Bezier curve" you mean "cubic Bezier curve."

The parameter equation for a cubic Bezier curve is as follows.

```
B(U, t) = U * w(t)           (2x1 column vector)

U = [U1 U2 U3 U4]            (2x4 matrix)

       [    (1-t)^3      ]
w(t) = [3 * (1-t)^2 * t  ]   (4x1 column vector)
       [3 * (1-t)   * t^2]
       [              t^3]
```

The four column vectors of `U` are four consecutive points on one of your cubic Bezier curves.

Given two cubic Bezier curves `B(U, t)` and `B(V, t)`, you want to determine whether there exist any `t0` and `t1` in `[0,1]` such that `B(U, t0) = B(V, t1)`. Those are your intersection points.

To solve that equation, you'll need to solve for the roots of a system of two 3rd-degree, 2-variable polynomials.  If you look at all the distinct `t0` values among those roots, that will tell you all the intersection points for your cubic Bezier curves `B(U, t)` and `B(V, t)`.